# VirtualBox on Windows 7 doesn't recognize SD card for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

On Windows 7 I am trying to get Ubuntu to run in the VirtualBox and I need it to recognize the SD card drive. The problem is that it's not finding it. Please advise.

UPDATE:
I see that the SD Card is under Disc Drives in the Device Manager (screenshot below).

[image]

UPDATE 12/3/13 9:50
I have tried a usb adapter for an SD card and this is what I see in the settings:

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled guest additions?

Comment: how is your SD card reader exposed to the system? USB? something else? You can check this in device manager I believe

Comment: @BenPlont I don't know what is a guest addition. I can't find online something that will help me understand it. Can you please tell me what it is and how it would help me to recognize the SD card drive?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I found in the Device Manager the SD Card is under Disc Drives (see my screenshot above).

Comment: @SBel, guest additions allows the vm to access some host hardware like USB ports. http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html

Answer (score 1):

The simulated VirtualBox hardware does not include an SD card reader. You have two options:

1. use an external USB SD card reader;
2. see whether your SD card reader is on the USB bus, in which case a USB filter in the settings of the VM might, perhaps, be able to grant you access to it. You will just have to try .it.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I will try a USB SD card adapter and we'll see then.

Comment: I did what you told me (to plug in a USB SD adapter) but I'm getting the settings that I've pasted in my initial post entry. Am I doing something wrong?